# Vote count differ

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, vote-count

In the users menu on the summary tab we have to lower right the overview of votes:

[image: User menu overview]

When I click on "view more":

[image: Votes detail]

The vote count differs? I checked that no votes from other stack exchange sites were counted in. This would also lead to different vote counts.

Comment: Oh, yes, that might be the answer. Sounds logical at least.

Comment: I've now confirmed that deleted posts are not counted on the voting tab; I found a question where I downvoted two answers, and one of those is now deleted but not listed on my tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The counts on your summary page are almost always going to be off, because:

- The votes tab counts up, down, deletion, undeletion, closure and reopen votes, your summary only counts up and down voting.
- The votes tab can show you up or down votes only, but those counts are only for still-listed posts. Deleted posts are not counted in that view, so the counts will be lower than your summary overview where deleted posts *are* counted.

For example, my upvote count is 'off' by 28 on the votes tab, or 0.96% of the total, but my downvote count has a 86 vote discrepancy, meaning 46.24% of my downvotes contributed to posts being deleted.

So, not a bug, luckily. :-)