# Misleading link description in the Summary tab for viewing all upvotes and downvotes cast

Tags: feature-request, status-review, voting, activity-summary

In the Summary tab on the Activity page, for example, on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/356843/justin), my total upvote count is 1084 and my total downvote count is 305, which makes a total of 1389 votes. This [includes votes on now-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/513150) questions and answers. The link which leads to a more detailed view (i.e., the [Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes) tab) says, "View all **1389** votes":

[image: Image showing vote counts; Misleading link description highlighted: "View all 1389 votes"]

Now this can be quite misleading, suggesting that I should be able to see all **1389** votes when I can only see a total of **1221** votes (upvotes + downvotes) in the Votes tab (as upvotes and downvotes on now-deleted posts are [not shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144755/vote-count-differ/144757#144757) in the Votes tab).

I think "View all 1389 votes" should read "**View all votes**". This is reasonable because it leads to the Votes tab which consists of "all votes" (reopen, deletion, undeletion, etc.), not just upvotes and downvotes. Deleted posts [should be shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290758/can-we-see-deleted-posts-which-we-downvoted) in the Upvote & Downvote subtabs as well, so that the discrepancy between vote counts in the Summary and Votes tabs can be taken care of once a user reaches the necessary 10,000 reputation to [view deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: Weirdly enough, when you open the Votes tab (e.g., following that link), deleted posts are displayed for all vote types _except_ upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: @41686d6564 only if you have > 10K reputation and it's always been like that for 10K+